# Mapply or lapply solution instead of iterative for-loop that sequentially declines values against different values of same vector

Tags: r

Trying to learn better solutions than for-loops and feel like this instance may lend itself to lapply or mapply.

I have a dataframe of two columns (volumes, months.passed) from different points in time I'm declining by a vector of decline values (decline.vector) whereby the decline start point changes based on the month passed + 1 month, until the end of the decline.vector.

Currently my solution, which works fine, is:

```
decline.vector <- c( 0.9,0.81,0.729,0.656,0.590,0.531,0.478, 0.430, 0.387,0.348)
months.passed <- c(2,4,5,6)
volumes <- c(10,20,10,20)
df <- data.frame(months.passed, volumes)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    build <- df$volumes[i] * cumprod(decline.vector[df$months.passed[i]+1:nrow(decline.vector),])
    build <- rbind(final,build)
}

return(build)
    [1] NA  NA  7.29    6.56    5.90    5.31    4.78    4.30    3.87    3.49
    [2] NA  NA  NA  NA  11.81   10.63   9.57    8.61    7.75    6.97
    [3] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  5.31    4.78    4.30    3.87    3.49
    [4] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  9.57    8.61    7.75    6.97
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, either using `lapply` or `mapply`, or even something instead of rbind?

Comment: The for-loop doesn't work for me since your code seems to be assuming that `decline.vector` is a matrix or data frame, rather than the vector you provide, among other issues. I can fix them and get an output similar to the one you provide, but without a real reproducible example, it's impossible to know the format you're expecting, which would be necessary to give you more useful information.

Comment: Ty divibisan, didn't realize I actually select the decline.vector from a data frame using dplyr in my actual code, did not think it would make a difference here for the example but see it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `mapply`

```
out1 <- t(mapply(
  function(x, y, z = decline.vector) {
    n <- length(z)
    c(rep(NA, y), x * z[(y + 1):n]) 
  },
  x = volumes,
  y = months.passed
))
out1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]   NA   NA 7.29 6.56  5.9  5.31 4.78  4.3 3.87  3.48
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA 11.8 10.62 9.56  8.6 7.74  6.96
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  5.31 4.78  4.3 3.87  3.48
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA 9.56  8.6 7.74  6.96
```

---

A vectorized option where we make use of matrix multiplication

```
out2 <- t(t(volumes)) %*% t(decline.vector)
```

Next we use a matrix to insert `NA`s at the first `months.passed` columns for each row

```
out2[cbind(rep(1:length(months.passed), months.passed),
           sequence(months.passed))] <- NA
```

Result

```
identical(out1, out2)
# [1] TRUE
```

**data**

```
decline.vector <- c(0.9, 0.81, 0.729, 0.656, 0.590, 0.531, 0.478, 0.430, 0.387, 0.348)
volumes <- c(10, 20, 10, 20)
months.passed <- c(2, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you for doing this markus despite my reproducible example shortfall.